# How to capture error response body and error code in post call where the response is not 200 via java code?

Tags: java, post, http-post, postman

I am writing the below code, but that is only capturing response body when response code is 200. For all other occasions it is failing.

Picture -
[postman post call and response where response code is not equal to 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFQRL.png)

For example when response code 409, the code is throwing error with

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 409 for URL: http://fetch.product/v1/products/PD16798270/validate
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:58)**

Code I am using below -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
     
     String url = "http://fetch.product/v1/products/PD16798270/validate";    
     URL u = new URL(url);
    
     StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
     byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
     
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");      
     
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
     
     Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
     String response = sb.toString();
     System.out.println(response);
     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the request returns an error response, you can read it from the connection's "error stream". For example, this would read the body whether the request returned success or error:

```
InputStream input;
if (conn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
    input = conn.getErrorStream();
} else {
    input = conn.getInputStream();
}

Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This is working absolutely fine man !!!...
Saved my day.
The o/p is now coming properly as below - 
{
  "state" : "Created",
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "ARTICLE_HAS_NO_AUTHORS",
    "category" : "Article"
  } ]
}

Can you help me how to segregate the part  -  "ARTICLE_HAS_NO_AUTHORS" from error response ?

I want only ARTICLE_HAS_NO_AUTHORS in the java code o/p.

Comment: That data format is called JSON, it's best to use a library to parse it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java